# Lotus Notes: Notes.ini $enablealarms

Tags: lotus-notes

recently i have observed that $enablealarms entry, in the notes.ini sometimes is set to $enablealarms=0 instead  $enablealarms=1.
I'm the only progrogrammer in my company and i want to know what are the ways to turn this value from 1 to 0. I'm sure that i haven't modify it and i'm also sure that the user haven't modify it too. So how is it possible that value was configured to 0 ? i'm sure that one month ago it was 1. 
In the user preference, under Mail general tab, "show popup" checkbox is checked.  Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to set this:

- on the client in the preferences tab (you found that one)
- via policy (mail- policy or desktop- policy)
- with coding (@Environment( ) or NotesSession.SetEnvironmentString)
- directly in the notes.ini- file (login- script, any other text manipulation)

Check these possibilitites, probably you find the reason

Comment: A notes.ini setting that starts with a $ character is almost certainly set by an application via @Environment or SetEnvironmentString.